# Does the accuracy of a regression learner depend on the way we feed data?

Tags: regression, sequence-modeling

Consider a plot of points as such:

[image]

As one notices, this looks like an alternating sequence. Further, it can be divided into two subsequences as $a_{\text{odd}}$ and $a_{\text{even}}$ as they seem to be part of a *decay* envelope separately.

Instead of feeding the entire sequence for the model to learn, if I feed the two subsequences separately, would it be able to predict data more accurately? My intuition says yes because the two subsequences are "nicer" than the sequence as a whole.

Comment: What statistical model do you have in the mind? Probably not linear regression nor logistic regression, right?

Comment: @CloudCho Sorry for the late reply. I noticed that even linear regression gives a very accurate value.

Comment: Do you evaluate your linear regression model by prediction at saturation period (the plat line)? What if you use data from zero to around 10? I don't think linear regression working on oscillation/transition period.

Comment: @CloudCho Thats correct. To be more specific, I used sklearn's linear fit function. With only first three input values, it could predict the next 50 values with very high accuracy.

Comment: "Only first three" Do you mean f(x=1), f(x=2), and f(x=3)?

Comment: @CloudCho yep that is correct

Comment: It is hard to believe only there oscillated points could give saturation point with Linear Regression. There is no other suggestion so far, so I guess the output of regression depends on your data. If you have any research on your own question, please feel free post on Answer section. It is ok..just not marked as Accepted, so other(s) may come later and share different points.

Comment: @CloudCho I understand. Would you be willing to connect on any social platform so that I can share the program and more about it to you?

Comment: I made a chat room at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149766/regression-input-data. Please, come hand share the code and etc.